# sql - total avg in groupby query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the avg salary  for each day and in the same table I want to see the avg for all the week (total avg)

```
select weekday,avg(salary) as avg_salary
from table1
group by weekday
```

what I need to add in order to find the yellow cell?

[image]

Comment: It would really help us to answer if you would post sample data, expected output etc. Try reading through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and editing your question

Comment: thank , I add photo to make it clear

Comment: @rafine, you know it is much better to provide the sample data and desired output as text rather than a picture. Picture is not really helpful in coding related forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the avg() regardless of weekday to your result with union all:

```
select weekday,avg(salary) from table1 group by weekday
union all
select max(0),avg(salary) from table1;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fee43876447066e2c186666e000da72a)

Please next time pay attention to give some sample data. You can use Dbfiddle as I did.

BTW, when I started writing, I didn't see SQL server tag. Now you have it, then this is the simpler one:

```
select weekday,avg(salary) from table1 group by weekday with rollup
```

Comment: `max(0)` um - You can include any constant in the select list without aggregating it or including it in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: And you could add the rollup query to the dbfiddle as well. Still upvoted.

Comment: @SMor, same result.

Comment: `with rollup` is deprecated, you should use `group by rollup(weekday)`

Comment: @Charlieface, it still works in SQL server 2019. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=78a37e59a9d97e522624bab7b5590a2f

Comment: I said deprecated, not discontinued. And it's not even exactly deprecated: the wording [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#group-by-column-expression--n--with--cube--rollup-) is "This syntax is provided for backward compatibility only. Avoid using this syntax in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this syntax."

Comment: @Charlieface, I didn't see your point really. We don't need to find something fancier, it works, right? What happens when you use it?

Comment: it's not about fancy, it's about what is approved and supported syntax. What happens is that you get technical debt down the road when Microsoft eventually discontinue it, and you perpetuate more code online pushing this. Whereas if you just use the approved syntax, it's actually less typing and is more understandable. `group by weekday with rollup` becomes `group by rollup(weekday)` note that this allows you to add other levels, for example `group by otherColumn, rollup(weekday)` which is the equivalent of `group by grouping sets ( (otherColumn, weekday), (otherColumn) )`

Comment: @Charliface, thanks. It is not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUPING SETS` for this.

```sql
select
  weekday,
  avg(salary) as avg_salary
from table1
group by grouping sets (
    (weekday),
    ()
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cb40fac05e41703340c7e216da906449)

`ROLLUP` also works, but is less flexible.